# Get rid of white space between bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Helo!
How can I get rid of the white space between the bars? I don't want space between the bares in the plot.

```
ggplot(global.ratios_gather,aes(x=Timeslot, y=N, fill=Section)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack", size=5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkseagreen","deepskyblue","greenyellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: Add `colour = Section` within `aes()`.